# Emails moved from Inbox to Public Folders still appear on BlackBerry

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010, blackberry, public-folders

I have user who moves emails from his Inbox into Public Folders from within Outlook. The problem is that these messages still appear on his blackberry.

Deleted Messages go, messages moved to other email folders, such as a subfolder in his inbox move, but any messages moved outside the messaging structure is not deleted.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked on a Blackberry. Have you tried the `Reconcile Now` option?

Comment: Reconcile Now still shows emails that have been moved, it's been tried :(

Comment: What BES version?

Comment: BES version 5.0 with SP3

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

Inbox --> Menu --> Options --> Message Display and Actions
Hide Filed Messages = Tick

Inbox --> Menu --> Options --> Email Reconciliation
Wireless reconcile = Tick
On Conflicts = mailbox wins

Resync

When my BB starts to mess up, I tend to wipe and reset it up again.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Same problem resolved by doing this:

Inbox --> Menu --> Options --> Message Display and Actions Hide Filed Messages - and ticking 'Hide filed messages' and also 'Hide sent messages'.